# PHP and MYSQL Based Login Errors

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am creating a PHP and MYSQL Login System and I am receiving the errors below. I am using this tutorial: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lta1r9xhk2u2ef0/3592029.doc. I can't seem to find the problem.

**Errors:**

> **Notice**: Undefined index: logged_in in /home/username/public_html/campusconnect/includes/login.inc.php on line 13
>
> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function real_escape_string() in /home/username/public_html/campusconnect/includes/login.inc.php on line 35

**login.inc.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Include required MySQL configuration file and functions
require_once('config.inc.php');
require_once('functions.inc.php');

// Start session
session_start();

// Check if user is already logged in
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {

// If user is already logged in, redirect to main page
redirect('http://campusconnect.ericsilva.me/index.php');
} 
else {
// Make sure that user submitted a username/password and username only consists of     alphanumeric chars
if ((!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password'])) OR     (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username']))) {
    redirect('http://campusconnect.ericsilva.me/login.php');
}

// Connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Unable to connect to database: %s", 
    mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// Escape any unsafe characters before querying database
real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" .     md5($password) . "'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// If one row is returned, username and password are valid
if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) {
    // Set session variable for login status to true
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    redirect('http://campusconnect.ericsilva.me/index.php');
} 
else {
    // If number of rows returned is not one, redirect back to login screen
    redirect('http://campusconnect.ericsilva.me/login.php');
}
}

?>
```

**functions.inc.php**

```
 <?php

/**
* Crucial Functions for Application
*
* @package tpc_tutorials
* @file    /includes/functions.inc.php
*
* Redirects to specified page
*
* @param string $page Page to redirect user to
* @return void
*/

function redirect($page) {
    header('Location: ' . $page);
    exit();
}

/**
* Check login status
*
* @return boolean Login status
*/

function check_login_status() {
// If $_SESSION['logged_in'] is set, return the status
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    return $_SESSION['logged_in'];
}
    return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: In `login.inc.php` do `if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true)` and use `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Change `real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
real_escape_string($_POST['password']);` to `$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);` that is part of a problem. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the variable isn't defined.

You should first call **isset()** function to check.

Example:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Fatal error: Call to undefined function real_escape_string()**

```
$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Its the right way of using `real_escape_string`. If again error occures after using this,you have to check your `php.ini` file and make sure that this line is uncommented in your php.ini

```
extension=mysql.so
```

And I think its better to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` since `mysql` is deprecated.

**For Notice: Undefined index: logged_in** ,

use `if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))`instead of `if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true)`

Source LINK : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: *"For Fatal error: Call to undefined function real_escape_string()"* - [`Read my comment to OP`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235631/php-and-mysql-based-login-errors#comment39312344_25235631) it has nothing to do with `extension=mysql.so`, it's the way is using it. Is not passing `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` to it.

Comment: Ok i ll edit my answer then ...

Answer (score 0):

**Please try to use like this**

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

**instead of this**

// Escape any unsafe characters before querying database

```
real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Comment: Do go over OP's code again, and *very carefully*. Is just using it wrong. Plus, is using `mysqli_` and not `mysql_`

Comment: -1 for using `mysql_` functions when OP is clearly using `mysqli_` functions, but is using it wrong, as previously stated above.

Comment: Your edit lacks DB connection to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Read up on the function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - as per the manual's example `$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);` - and read [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235631/php-and-mysql-based-login-errors#comment39312344_25235631) to OP.

Comment: Whoever declined my flag should read up on how PHP/SQL functions work.